# doesn't work send in res.status(409).send('error')

Tags: node.js, reactjs

my back-end(node js) when status code is 200 send data to front-end correctly but when status code is not 200 dont send anything to front-end

front-end code:

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    try {
        e.preventDefault()
        const result = await createPost(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)))
        console.log(result) // ==> if status code !== 200 => result=undefined 
        if (result.status === 200) toast.success('پست با موفقیت ساخته شد')

    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
        if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400)
            toast.error('لطفا کلیه موارد را پر کنید');
    }
}
```

backend code

```
router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let post = new Post({
        postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
        postImageUrl: req.body.postImageUrl,
        postContent: req.body.postContent,
        postTags: req.body.postTags
    });

    post = await post.save();

    res.status(200).send(post);
});
```

I expected to run catch section if back-end response status is not 200, 
but when status code is 400 ex.response and ex.response.status is undefined.

when i run this, my console in browser log this messages:

> POST http://localhost:3800/api/post 400 (Bad Request)
>
> createPost.jsx:19 undefined
>
> createPost.jsx:23 TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of
>   undefined
>       at CreatePost.handleSubmit (createPost.jsx:20)

my validation function is:

```
const validate = post => {
    const schema = {
        postTitle: Joi.string().required(),
        postDate: Joi.string(),
        postImageUrl: Joi.string(),
        postContent: Joi.string().required(),
        postTags: Joi.array(),
        postLike: Joi.number()
    };

    return Joi.validate(post, schema);
};
```

my create post component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createPost } from '../../services/postService'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import _ from 'lodash'

class CreatePost extends Component {
    state = {
        postTitle: '',
        postImageUrl: '',
        postContent: '',
        postTags: []
    }

    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        try {
            e.preventDefault()

            const result = await createPost(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)))
            console.log(result) // ==> if status code !== 200 => result=undefined 
            if (result.status === 200) toast.success('پست با موفقیت ساخته شد')

        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex)
            if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400)
                toast.error('لطفا کلیه موارد را پر کنید');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form
                className="form-group bg-light border rounded m-2 shadow p-5"
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            >
                <label className="col-md-4 control-label" htmlFor="txtTitle">
                    عنوان پست
                </label>
                <input
                    id="txtTitle"
                    name="postTitle"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="عنوان"
                    className="form-control input-md m-2"
                    value={this.state.postTitle}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ postTitle: e.target.value })}
                />

                <input
                    id="txtImageUrl"
                    name="postImageUrl"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="لینک عکس (الزامی نیست)"
                    className="form-control input-md m-2"
                    value={this.state.postImageUrl}
                    onChange={e =>
                        this.setState({ postImageUrl: e.target.value })
                    }
                />

                <textarea
                    name="postContent"
                    className="form-control m-2"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="متن پست"
                    value={this.state.postContent}
                    onChange={e =>
                        this.setState({ postContent: e.target.value })
                    }
                />

                <label className="col-md-4 control-label" htmlFor="txtTags">
                    برچسب ها
                </label>

                <input
                    id="txtTags"
                    name="postTags"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="برچسب را با (,) از هم جدا کنید"
                    className="form-control input-md m-2"
                    value={this.state.postTags}
                    onChange={e =>
                        this.setState({
                            postTags: _.split(e.target.value, ',')
                        })
                    }
                />

                <button className="btn btn-success m-5">ساخت پست جدید</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default CreatePost;
```

and create post service is :

```
export function createPost(post) {
    return http.post(config.api_post, post)
}
```

and http service is:
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token']=localStorage.getItem('token')

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
    const expectedError =
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status < 500

    if (!expectedError){
        console.log('Logging the error:', error)
        toast.error('خطایی رخ داده است')

        return Promise.reject(error)        
    }
})

export default {
    get: axios.get,
    post: axios.post,
    put: axios.put,
    delete: axios.delete,
    patch: axios.patch
}
```

and github repository of this is :
https://github.com/mehdiparastar/personal-site.git

how to solve this problem?

Comment: not the component this import `import { createPost } from '../../services/postService'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `axios.interceptor`. Normally http `4xx` errors goes to `catch` block if you `try/catch` on `await axios`. But you've intercepted and changed the behaviour.

In your interceptor logic `expectedError` will evaluate to `true` for http `4xx` errors:

```
const expectedError =
      error.response &&
      error.response.status >= 400 &&
      error.response.status < 500
// expectedError === true
```

And this block will not be evaulated

```
if (!expectedError){
    console.log('Logging the error:', error)
    toast.error('خطایی رخ داده است')

    return Promise.reject(error)        
}
```

Since you don't have an `else` block and no default return value, the interceptor returns `undefined` (default return value in JS) which is handled in the `try` block since it's not an error

So the error is not from `catch` block:

```
const result = await createPost(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)))
// result is undefined
if (result.status === 200) // <-- error is from this line
```

So you can simply have an `else` block or a default `retrun` like:

```
if (!expectedError){
    ...
    return Promise.reject(error)        
} else {
    return error // or Promise.resolve(error)
}

// OR

if (!expectedError){
    ...
    return Promise.reject(error)        
}

return error //etc
```